# What characters may be included in instagram's shortcode?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to validate user's input. Maybe, someones know what characters can be included in shortcode?

I have checked Instagram's documentation, but haven't found any information regarding it.

For example in [pinterest's documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/) there is information about shortcode:

```
Creates a logging tag for analytics. Tags may include the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore, and are constrained to 32 characters.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are  valid: `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` `_` `-`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.